# How to get back the first form in terms of absolute function from the component form of a function?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=|x|+|x-1|$. And we know that $f(x)$ can be written as 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x-(x-1), & x<0\\
0+1, & x=0\\
x-(x-1), &x\in (0, 1)\\
1+0, &x=1\\
x+(x-1)& x>1
\end{cases}$$
which is 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-2x+1, & x<0\\
1, & x=0\\
1, &x\in (0, 1)\\
1, &x=1\\
2x-1& x>1
\end{cases}$$
i.e. $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-2x+1, & x<0\\
1, & x\in [0, 1]\\
2x-1& x>1
\end{cases}$$

My query is: suppose that the last expression is given. Viz the component form of $f(x)$ is given. Is it possible or is there any method or procedure through which we can obtain the first expression in the form of sum of absolute value functions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: you have cases like $f(x)=|2x+2|=|x+1|+|x+1|$.

Solution for the case $f=|f_1|+\cdots+|f_n|$ with $f_i$ a first degree polynomial with root $x_i$ and $x_i\ne x_j$ for $i\ne j$

The "angled points" ofe the graph will be $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. Write
$$f(x)=|a_1(x-x_1)+b_1|+\cdots+|a_n(x-x_n)+b_n|.$$
Can you continue?

Comment: I didn't realize that "warning" unless you mentioned. Thank you for that. Between, any other method?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath I can not think of another, but the "angled points" will be essential in any case.

Comment: fine. thank you for your suggestions